# Im having trouble with javafx on net beans reading a .get error message below

Tags: java, javafx, get, set

This is the line I am having an error with: **list.setdata_item(stack.getdata_item());**

It says "**can not find symbol symbol: method getdata_item**" what do I need to do to get it to read? If you are framilar with net beans it tries to auto fill and when I type in ".get" it only shows .get(int i).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that autocomplete only shows .get(int i) indicates that 'stack' has no method called getdata_item(). I assume that stack is a Stack object, so basically you can only push and pop (or addElement etc. which have the same functionality).

If you need a specific element from your stack, you have to provide the index (e.g. to get the fourth element use stack.get(3)) or you will have to provide the object you're looking for: indexOf(Object). That will give you the index of the first(!) occurrence which you can then use for get(index).

I almost suspect though that your Stack data structure is not the right one for what you're trying to do (without further info). Perhaps you should consider a hash table or an ArrayList instead?